# Can't enable local mode in 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

I've just download the 2.8 and can't find the, I think it was the local button that was next to the layers in the 2.7x to enable different layers per viewport, and the "/" button of my keyboard doesn't work neither, are these features removed or have they changed the shortcuts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about missing features in experimental development software

Comment: Ok then isn't ready now I suppose, I was just curious because the 2.8 will be out after the blender conference and didn't know if they change/remove that

Comment: ...and can't find the, ...what??

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing they took it out, since its functionality was a bit redundant. You can accomplish the same thing with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide everything not selected. I noticed they also seemed to have removed the box hide functionality, also redundant. It could be part of the larger effort to streamline the UI, probably a good thing.